# C++ 'Vector':'struct' type redefinition, tried everything on this and still getting the same error

Tags: c++

So im making a game using the sdl2 libraries but the simple struct i have created is causing a large error. I have viewed a lot of the errors that people have with the rerdefinition but everything i have tried fails and i dont know why. I am admittedly new to c++ but i have searched all over stack and tried all the things suggested and nothing has worked for me. Not even got to the graphical part yet and not got much hope by this point.

The header file contains this code:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

struct Vector
{
    float x, y;
};

class Player
{
    Vector position;
    int health;
    int ammoCount;
    int score;
    bool lifeState;

public:
    Player();
    ~Player();
    Player(Vector pos, int hp, int ammo, int scoreboard, bool alive);
    void update();

    static const int MAX_HEALTH = 100;
    static const int MIN_HEALTH = 0;

    int getHealth();
    void increaseHealth(int increment);
    void decreaseHealth(int decrement);
};

#endif
```

Source File:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Player.h"


Player::Player()
{
}

Player::Player(Vector pos, int hp, int ammo, int scoreboard, bool alive)
{
    this->position = pos;
    this->health = hp;
    this->ammoCount = ammo;
    this->score = scoreboard;
    this->lifeState = alive;

}


Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::update()
{

}

int Player::getHealth()
{
    return health;
}

void Player::increaseHealth(int increment)
{
    health += increment;

    if (health > MAX_HEALTH)
        health = MAX_HEALTH;
}

void Player::decreaseHealth(int decrement)
{
    health -= decrement;

    if (health < MIN_HEALTH)
        health = MIN_HEALTH;
}
```

Error Fixed with the above code but still occuring within the below code even though they are not linked. Thank you for the help so far everyone!

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ENEMY_H_
#define ENEMY_H_

struct Vector 
{
    float x, y;
};

class Enemy
{
    Vector position;
    int health;
    int ammoCount;
    bool lifeState;

public:
    Enemy();
    Enemy(Vector pos, int hp, int ammo, bool alive);
    ~Enemy();


    void update();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Does your `pch.h` (precompiled header) by any chance have `#include "Player.h"` in it?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: no, ive left the pch.h alone

Comment: 'Vector': 'struct' type redefinition

Comment: Is the error a secret? Please provide a [mre] with the full error message

Comment: The code provided does not produce the error (or any error; it appears to be okay).  The bug is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Off topic, but it is not a good idea to write an empty destructor in this day and age of C++.  By writing an empty destructor, you're changing the traits for the class (the class is no longer trivially destructible), thus could cause the compiler to produce less-efficient code.

Comment: The full error message informs you where the first definition is and where the second definition met.

Comment: what do you mean by a secret? i have another class with the same struct but they produce the same error. there are other errors but they all relate to the struct

Comment: Im just using the information provided by my university to try and create a game. as i said i am new to c++ that is why i am asking for help. They have not at this point in time told us to fill the destructor with anything

Comment: ok thank you @S.M. ill see if that helps

Comment: *they have not at this point in time told us to fill the destructor with anything* -- That's my point.  Get rid of it until you really need to destroy something.  C++ taught in universities usually use old or bad material, and are not up to date on the latest C++ best practices.

Comment: managed to remove the error from the player.h but it is still occuring in the enemy.h even tho the two are not linked

Comment: editted to show the new error. Thank you for the help so far